# Update a field looking a value in other table between ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Good afternoon, I will greatly appreciate your help with my next problem
I have this two tables

**CP TABLE**

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------+
| COUNTRY | Postal Code1 | Postal Code2 | CODECP |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------+
| BR      | 30000-000    | 32469-999    | BR1    |
| BR      | 32470-000    | 32499-999    | BR2    |
| BR      | 32600-000    | 32699-999    | BR3    |
| MX      | 25000        | 25399        | MX1    |
| MX      | 25400        | 25419        | MX2    |
| MX      | 25420        | 25469        | MX3    |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------+
```

**PARTNERS TABLE**

```
+----------+--------------+---------+
| PCOUNTRY | PPostal Code | PCODECP |
+----------+--------------+---------+
| BR       | 30000-000    |         |
| MX       | 25233        |         |
| BR       | 32475-001    |         |
| MX       | 25431        |         |
| MX       | 32650-023    |         |
+----------+--------------+---------+
```

that I want to do is to update the field `PCODECP` in **Partners table** with the values that is in **CP Table**, `Country` and `PContry` is my relationship, the PPostal code is the value that I need to lookup in the corresponding range and `PCODECP` is the field I need to update with his correct code,here what should be the result

**RESULT**

```
+----------+--------------+---------+
| PCOUNTRY | PPostal Code | PCODECP |
+----------+--------------+---------+
| BR       | 30000-000    | BR1     |
| MX       | 25233        | MX1     |
| BR       | 32475-001    | BR2     |
| MX       | 25431        | MX3     |
| MX       | 32650-023    | BR3     |
+----------+--------------+---------+
```

Regards!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `join`:

```
select p.*, cp.codecp
from partners p left join
     cp
     on p.country = cp.country and
        p.postal_code >= cp.postal_code1 and
        p.postal_code <= cp.postal_code2;
```

This uses `left join`, so it keeps all rows in the first table, even when there are no matches.

Presumably, you are using SQL Server, so the `update` looks like this:

```
update p
    set p.codecp = cp.codecp
from partners p join
     cp
     on p.country = cp.country and
        p.postal_code >= cp.postal_code1 and
        p.postal_code <= cp.postal_code2;
```

Comment: Thank for your Help Gordon Linoff, , I have a doubt, don't need the "update" function to updated de PCODECP field?, how the code should be ?